# PayPal sending payment emails to primary email but NOT business email?

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal web payment standard on 2 of my websites. With the payment form having `business` being a non-primary email in my PayPal account, the payment email (Notification of payment received) is still being sent to my primary email, about 50% of the time or so.

This is really weird.

While it may not be that big a deal most of the time but it may come very unhandy in situations such as when we need to search through the notification emails that are randomly scattered across 2 different email inboxes.

This behavior doesn't make any sense at all. What can I do to fix this and make PayPal consistently send the payment notification email to the business email specified in payment form `business` field rather than the primary email of my PayPal account?

Comment: Have you talked to PayPal?? What do they tell you?

Comment: While you did mention you have websites, I don't think this is the place for this question because it sounds like an issue that can only be fixed either through the paypal site or through server-side coding.

Comment: Have you verified your web links to PayPal so they are using the proper email address? If those are all correct, contact PayPal.

Comment: Who the he** migrated my question here? It's by all means meant for webmasters not normal PayPal users!